# Managing loads of web forms

Tags: jquery, css, forms, kohana

I'm currently working on a web project that is on a larger scale than I'm used to.
The website has a frontend for registered users which consists of 10 different subpages which all have forms.

But my problem is how to create and manage these forms by way of CSS and jQuery.
Is there a simple or rather dynamic way to create the forms?

I feel that the form creation could easily get out of control and everything becomes a mess.

The system is built on the Kohana framework.

Comment: You'll need to explain further. Why is the creation and management of these forms problematic? How would it "get out of control" and "become a mess"? Why do you need a "dynamic" way of generating them?

Comment: @maxedison, basically im desperate after some kind of proper form framework that can "globalize" my form creations. Im trying to make my own framework for this, but i find it quite messy with different jQuery tools and styles all over the place. Furthermore i have never created this kind of framework so designwize im a bit lost.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. You already have Kohana, why build another framework? Use Kohana's controllers, form helpers and validators. Forms are always going to be complex, there is not easy way. I have used Zend Framework's Forms with global configurations and it's not easy either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kohana-Formo](https://github.com/bmidget/kohana-formo) looks like what you want.